# Copy paste gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, copy-paste

How do you copy (rightclick) some columns from a gridview (asp.net) and paste it in excel? When I try I get one line with all the data pasted in excel, and it should be in the same columns and rows as the gridview.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks. I made a button and exported it to a csv file. The code below does the job.

```
  Private Sub ExportGrid(ByVal gridname As String)
    Dim kolonner As Integer
    If gridname.ToString = GridView1.ToString Then
        kolonner = 5
    Else
        kolonner = 10
    End If

    'Lav DT 
    Dim dtUse As DataTable = New DataTable
    If gridname = "GridView1" Then
        dtUse = dt2.Copy()
    Else
        '  dtUse = dt2.Copy
    End If

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.csv")
    ' Response.Charset = "System.Text.Encoding.Default"
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
    'text/html
    'Response.ContentType = "System.Text.Encoding.Default"
    Response.ContentType = "text/html"

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each clm As DataColumn In dtUse.Columns
        sb.Append(clm.ColumnName.ToString + ";"c)
    Next
    'append new line
    sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)

    Dim tt As String = sb.ToString

    For Each row As DataRow In dtUse.Rows
        For Each CLM2 As DataColumn In dtUse.Columns
            'add separator
            sb.Append(row(CLM2).ToString + ";"c)
        Next
        'append new line
        sb.Append(vbCr & vbLf)
    Next
    Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try Using a custom context Menu like "Export to excel", and write code for it.
In your your code take all the Values in a row and separate them with a comma (Making a **csv** formatted row) and then append each Row with a `"\r\n"`.

The data will become in following format.

```
col1 , col2 , col3 \r\n
data1, data2 data3 \r\n
data1, data2 data3 \r\n
data1, data2 data3 \r\n
data1, data2 data3 \r\n
```

That way it will be properly formatted to be exported in Excel. Just add the Final string to Clipboard.

Comment: informations on how to to do that in asp.net/javascript would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

People dont copy paste a whole GridView.
It tedious and error prone.
Its your duty as a programmer to do that for them.
Place a nice [**Export to Excel Button**](http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&q=gridview+export+to+excel+vb.net) on top of the GridView for that

Comment: Ok solved. I did not paste the gridview but created a button, that exported it to a csv.file. This code works: